# Compute a field in Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hey Guys here is a document in my collection.
{
Player_Name: Sandeep Nair
Player_TotalWeightedPoints: 80
Player_Rank: 23
}

There are close to 200 such documents. The Player_Rank field is a function of the total Weighted points, sorted in descending order. The player with the highest weighted points having rank 1 and so on.
I have 2 use cases

1. I need to display the rank to the user(player) when he logs into the webapp.
2. I need to compute the fresh rank based on the match score every time a match takes place.

How do I compute this Rank field in Mongo DB. ? Can someone throw some light please.

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets in your question.

Comment: there are no code snippets dude,,I am asking a question to understand if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear but i do have some suggestions for you.

For case 1:

it would be better if you assign some id with each player in order to get its other relevant details associated with him .

for now , let's assume that Player A has logged in with uid:123 , you can use

```
var data  = db.player.find({}, {uid:123});
var rank = data.Player_Rank;
```

the rank of the player will be stored in rank variable which can be used anywhere in page .

For case 2 :

After the input of points is inserted , sort the list with respect to points .

```
db.player.find().sort({Player_TotalWeightedPoints : -1})
```

now we have sorted the list , now we can assign player rank by using range from 1 to 200

```
db.players.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "Player_Rank": { $range: [ 1, 200] }
    }
}])
```

this is the best which i can advice by looking at your question.

Comment: thanks Avinash. I got it. So the confusion in my head was answered by your $range comment. Can you please explain that a little further. Also by aggregating and then projecting Rank like this will it get stored in the DB?

Comment: at first the data will be sorted in db , after which with the help of $range we will assign updated rank of the player . it is better to use different collection after each game for better data tracking